# Read More Script

Tags: html

I am using a script for limit the paragraph for few words only so for that m using the script of readmore..but the problem is it collapse the paragraph wherever I click on text whereas I want it to be collapse when Clicked on >>more link..so I request anyone to help me out of this what to do that it will not accept the click on text.

```
                    <!--readmore script-->
                <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {

                    // Grab all the excerpt class
                    $('.excerpt').each(function () {

                        // Run formatWord function and specify the length of words display to viewer
                        $(this).html(formatWords($(this).html(), 15));

                        // Hide the extra words
                        $(this).children('span').hide();

                    // Apply click event to read more link
                    }).click(function () {

                        // Grab the hidden span and anchor
                        var more_text = $(this).children('span.more_text');
                        var more_link = $(this).children('a.more_link');

                        // Toggle visibility using hasClass
                        // I know you can use is(':visible') but it doesn't work in IE8 somehow...
                        if (more_text.hasClass('hide')) {
                            more_text.show();
                            more_link.html(' &raquo; hide');        
                            more_text.removeClass('hide');
                        } else {
                            more_text.hide();
                            more_link.html(' &laquo; more');            
                            more_text.addClass('hide');
                        }

                        return false;

                    });
                });

                // Accept a paragraph and return a formatted paragraph with additional html tags
                function formatWords(sentence, show) {

                    // split all the words and store it in an array
                    var words = sentence.split(' ');
                    var new_sentence = '';

                    // loop through each word
                    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

                        // process words that will visible to viewer
                        if (i <= show) {
                            new_sentence += words[i] + ' ';

                        // process the rest of the words
                        } else {

                            // add a span at start
                            if (i == (show + 1)) new_sentence += ' <span class="more_text hide">';      

                            new_sentence += words[i] + ' ';

                            // close the span tag and add read more link in the very end
                            if (words[i+1] == null) new_sentence += '</span><a href="#" class="more_link"> &raquo; more</a>';
                        }       
                    } 

                    return new_sentence;

                }   
                </script>
                    <!--readmore script-->


<body>
<p class="excerpt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>


  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)....</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Nobody is going to look through that. Try and cut it down, maybe have just the start of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about these small script? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/uEXvk/

## HTML

```
<p class="excerpt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>


  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)....</p>
```

## CSS

```
a {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

## JQUERY

```
    var orgContent = $('.excerpt').html();
    var txtContent = $('.excerpt').text().substr(0, 50) + '... <a id="morelink">more</a>';
    $('.excerpt').html(txtContent);
    $("body").on("click", '#morelink', function(){
        $('.excerpt').html(orgContent);
        $('<a id="lesslink"> less</a>').appendTo('.excerpt');
    });
    $("body").on("click", '#lesslink', function(){
        $('.excerpt').html(txtContent);
    });
```

Comment: You are welcome, what about green tick? ;)

Comment: oh yes ofcrse sir u deserve this..and pls keep helping me sir thx a ton :)

Comment: For my description column I used this jQuery script, but it overwrites all the descriptions as a copy of the first one.